# RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

May be everything okay but i'm getting error. basically i'm add view resolver properties in application properties file, then run this project and open a browser, browser show this error **Whitelabel Error Page 404 file not found**.  I don't understand help me and suggested how to resolve this problem , i'm newbie in Spring Boot.in this blow  my project detail's .

**Error**

```
 2018-04-07 12:11:51.661 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.661 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.661 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Rendering view with name 'home' with model {} and static attributes {}
2018-04-07 12:11:51.684 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3087f725
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@7ba6a25a] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@6d6680cb] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.687 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp
2018-04-07 12:11:51.690 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.690 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@1a14f49d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.690 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.690 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@7b19df79] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-07 12:11:51.690 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] are [/**]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.691 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] are {}
2018-04-07 12:11:51.692 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@73797478]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-04-07 12:11:51.692 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@44abba94]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.692 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@f0e0b58]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] is: -1
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path contains "WEB-INF" or "META-INF".
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Ignoring invalid resource path [WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No matching resource found - returning 404
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 DEBUG 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-04-07 12:11:51.693 TRACE 3740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3087f725
```

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.ethxpay.book.ticket.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.emded:tomcat-embed-japer')

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '3.0' 
    compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version: '2.1' 
}
```

**application.properties**

```
    #Database Properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#View Resolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#JPA/Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#Log
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL:debug
logging.level.org.springframework: TRACE
logging.level.com: TRACE
```

**Controller Class**

```
    @RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

    @PostMapping("/createEmp")
    public void createEmp(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Employee emp = new Employee(request.getParameter("name"), request.getParameter("tel"),
                request.getParameter("address"), Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("sal")));

        employeeService.create(emp);
    }
}
```

**Project-Seed**

[image]

Comment: Don't put your JSP in `WEB-INF`. It should be one level higher.

Comment: i don't  understand please tell me more details @SeverityOne

Comment: Your JSPs should be in the `src/main/webapp` folder, not in `WEB-INF`. In addition, the `createEmp` method should return a `ModelAndView` instance. Whether this would solve your problem I can't say (yet), but these two points strike me as incorrect.

Comment: did not work @ServerityOne

Answer (score 11):

While using Maven and I was missing these dependencies -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have little to no knowledge on Gradle you can try to remove javax-servlet and jsp dependencies. As you already have tomcat and web dependencies added.
Also if you are using, jstl, you can use this dependency -

```
compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
```

Comment: After adding jasper and jstl dependencies, the White Label issue got resolved in my spring boot web application. Thank you Ajay Kumar.

Answer (score 2):

- Adding jasper dependency worked for me.
- The embedded tomcat needs the jasper dependency to render the jsp views in Spring boot 
  application.

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```
- And if you require to write iteration, control statements in your jsp pages then also 
  include JSTL i.e JSP Standard Tag Library in your pom.xml as follows:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.7'
```

The above dependency worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]

Spring-boot application for getting jsp pages

Changes required in application.properties

spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Changes in pom.xml for themleaf related changes : 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```